# Disable other click over image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have a list which has a jquery handler for a mouse click. I need to place an image within the list, but need a mouse click on the image to perform a different function. I was thinking some sort of unbind on mouseover and bind on mouseout but can not get it to work. Is there an easier method?

The problem I am having is it performs the two clickable events when I click the image.

JS

```
$(function () {
var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function (index) {
$(this).click(function () {
    alert("This is a click on the list")
}
});
});
```

html

```
<li id="tab" runat="server">Keywords <a class="fake-link" onclick="alert("This is an image click")"><img id="icon" src="images/icon.gif" style="float: right; visibility:visible"/></a></li>
```

So any ideas how I can only have the alert from the image click? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use a CSS background in the link and set the click event to the A-tag, not the LI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function () {
var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function (index) {
$(this).click(function (e) {
if($(e.target).attr('id')==='icon')){
//call that function which runs on image click
}
else {
    alert("This is a click on the list")
}
}
});
});
```

Edit: As puppybeard suggested here is another way if you want to have different function to run for all images in the li's

```
$(function () {
    var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function (index) {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
    if($(e.target).is('img'))){
    //call that function which runs on image click
    }
    else {
        alert("This is a click on the list")
    }
    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: This will work. `if($(e.target).is('img'))` is how you check if it's an image, if you want to only target the element type and not a specific id

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do because of event bubbling.
Event namespaces and .on() .off() would help.

For example:

```
var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li');

var someFunctionToPerform = function() {
alert('Imma list click event');
}

items.on('click.someEventNameSpace', someFunctionToPerform);

items.find('img').on({
    'mouseover': function() {
        items.off('click.someEventNameSpace');    
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
        items.on('click.someEventNameSpace', someFunctionToPerform);
    },
    'click': function() {
        alert('Imma list image click event!');
    }   
});
```

This code will unbind click event for list items after mouseover event on image inside the list and bind them back after mouseleave event on image.

That's probably the hard way, but still it should work. Other answer could be buggy in IE 8- because of different dirrection of event bubbling.